# how to disable "created" from SharePoint "When an item is created or modified" workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

Is there any way to have this workflow trigger be "When an item is MODIFIED" only and not created???

Answer (score 2):

In the workflow settings there is a checkbox that says when an item is created or when an item is modified. Make sure just the Start Workflow automatically when an item is changed is the only one checked.... see screenshot attached

[image]